# Matplotlib : Savefig not working in windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

My savefig code is not working in windows. Same code is working prefectly fine in Ubuntu. I just tried adding complete path too  using `getcwd()` but still getting the error.

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I saw some similar questions which suggest to put entire path, which is also not working.

```
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Calibri"
img_path = str(str('eleventh')+str('edfr')+str('dfg')+'.png')
path =  os.getcwd()+ '\/' + img_path

plt.savefig(path, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: No clue why you build your path this way. The correct way to do it would be `os.path.join(os.getcwd(),img_path)`. Also try to print your path before saving to spot any obvious mistakes.

Comment: @Repiklis I tried the way you suggested it prints the same path where my code is residing . I am still getting the same error hence posted